# How to pass in reference/parent ID into polymorphic child record via a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, activerecord, polymorphism

I have a double nested form and I need to save the ID of one of the parents in the child record. However, the parent record might not have an ID yet so I can't save the ID. How can I pass in this referenced ID? Thanks!

### Context

I'm somewhat new to Rails and am working on a homework app where a teacher can create a `Work`. A `Work` can have `Questions` and a `Question` has `Answers`. 
For a `Work`, a student can create a `Submission`. The `Submission` can have `Answers` (which are a response to the `Work`'s questions.

**Goal** Ultimately, I'd like to display the information for a student submission including the relevant `Work` information, `Answers` the student provided along with the `Question` they were answering.

I'm currently unable to create an `Answer` and have it reference the ID of the `Question` that it's nested in (which makes sense to me since at form submission, the `Question` might not exist and won't have an ID.

My questions are:

1. How can I pass in the parent/referenced `question_id` into `answer`?
2. If that isn't possible, how can I reorganize these models so that I can accomplish the goal above?
3. Is polymorphism the best use here or should I be using STI? (Or is this not relevant to my case)

### Code

#### My models:

models/work.rb

```
class Work < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :submissions
  has_many :questions # Allow for quizzes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: works
#
#  id               :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  description      :text
#  due_date         :datetime
#  name             :string
#  submittable      :boolean          default(TRUE)
#  url              :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#  course_id        :integer
#
```

models/submission.rb

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :work
  has_many :answers, as: :answerable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: submissions
#
#  id            :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  enrollment_id :integer
#  work_id       :integer
#  title         :string
#  content       :text
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null
#
```

models/question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :work
  has_many :answers, as: :answerable
  # has_many :answers, as: :answerable, inverse_of: :question
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates :value, presence: true, allow_nil: false
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id         :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  value      :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  work_id    :bigint(8)
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_questions_on_work_id  (work_id)
#
```

models/answer.rb

```
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :answerable, polymorphic: true

  validates :value, presence: true, allow_nil: false
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answers
#
#  id              :bigint(8)        not null, primary key
#  answerable_type :string
#  is_canon        :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  is_correct      :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  value           :string
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#  answerable_id   :bigint(8)
#  question_id     :bigint(8)
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_answers_on_answerable_id  (answerable_id)
#  index_answers_on_question_id    (question_id)
#
# Foreign Keys
#
#  fk_rails_...  (question_id => questions.id)
#
```

#### Controller

controller/works_controller.rb

```
class WorksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @work = Work.new(work_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @work.save
        format.html { redirect_to @work, notice: 'Work was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @work }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @work.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  private

    def work_params
      params.require(:work).permit(:name, :category_id, :course_id, :description, :url, :due_date, :published, :points, :grades_published,

        questions_attributes: [:id, :value, :_destroy,

          answers_attributes: [:id, :value, :question_id, :is_correct, :is_canon, :_destroy]

        ]

      )

    end

end
```

#### Views:

_form.html.slim

```
...
  / Questions
  .form-group.u-mt2x
    = form.fields_for :questions do |question|
      = render 'shared/question_fields', f: question
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Question', form, :questions, class: "u-button--New u-button--sm", partial: 'shared/question_fields'
```

_question_fields.html.slim

```
.nested-fields
  .form-group
    .form-group
      = f.label :value, "Question", :class => "required"
      = link_to_remove_association "remove question", f, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to remove this question?'}
    = f.text_field :value, class: "form-control"

  // Answers / Choices
  .form-group.u-mt2x
    = f.fields_for :answers do |answer|
      = render 'shared/answer_fields', f: answer
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'Add Choice', f, :answers, partial: "shared/answer_fields"
```

_answer_fields.html.slim

```
.nested-fields
  .form-group
    .form-group
      = f.label :value, "Answer Choice", :class => "required"
      = link_to_remove_association "remove choice", f, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to remove this answer?'}
    = f.text_field :value, class: "form-control"
  .form-group
    = f.label :is_correct, "This is the correct answer"
    div
      = f.label :is_correct, "Yes", value: true
      = f.radio_button :is_correct, true
      = f.label :is_correct, "No", value: false
      = f.radio_button :is_correct, false
    /= f.select :is_correct, options_for_select([["Yes", true], ["No", false]])
  // Hidden fields
  .form-group
    - if current_user.id == @work.course.owner.id
      = f.label :is_canon, "Canonical Choice"
    = f.hidden_field :is_canon, value: current_user.id == @work.course.owner.id, :readonly => true
  /.form-group
    - if current_user.id == @work.course.owner.id
      = f.label :question_id, "Question ID"
    = f.text_field :question_id, @question.id
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :submissions
  ...
  devise_for :users, :path => 'auth', :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

  get "works/index"
  resources :works do 
    member do 
      put 'toggle_publish'
      put 'toggle_publish_grades'
    end
  end
  ...
  root 'home#index'
end
```

### What I have tried/considered

1. Adding `inverse_of` to the `Question` model gives me an `ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.)` Additionally, it seems like `inverse_of` does not work well with `polymorphic` model relationships.

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :answers, as: :answerable, inverse_of: :question
  ...
end
```

2. I've also considered separating out the form such that the `Question`/`Answer` are not created on form submission but rather an AJAX request so that I can get the `question_id`.
3. On form submission, call `questions_controller` (which calls `answers_controller`) and have each create their own records rather than create everything within `works_controller`

### TLDR

I have a double nested form and I need to save the ID of one of the parents in the child record. However, the parent record might not have an ID yet so I can't save the ID. How can I pass in this referenced ID? Thanks!

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: I updated the description with my routes.rb file. I haven't added anything for `questions`/`answers` to routes though. Should I be?